# Grouping '.format()'-style logging messages in Sentry

Tags: python, logging, format, sentry

I use `SentryHandler` from `raven.handlers.logging` to track any logs of higher level within Sentry. My logging messages are dynamically populated with custom content with `.format()`, so the text message itself doesn't necessarily always have the same content. For example:

```
import logging
from raven.handlers.logging import SentryHandler
from raven.conf import setup_logging

# Create a "basic" logger
logger = logging.getLogger("root")

# Create a Sentry logger handler
sh = SentryHandler("https://******@sentry.io/******")
sh.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
setup_logging(sh)

# Send the desired message to Sentry via logger
if SomeInteresetingWarning():
    logger.warning("{} missing files in {} directiories!".format(num_files,num_dirs))
```

All good, only this causes every unique message to be considered as a unique Warning, which of course isn't true.

There is a nice [QA](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/773) covering this very problem on GitHub, but the solution provided there only applies to the strings, formatted with *old-fashioned* `%s`-style.

Does anybody know how to implement proper Sentry message grouping (aggregating) without having to redesign string formatting from `format()` back to `%s` placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles

The gist is to use a formatter with style="{".

Comment: This answer is misleading. Changing the formatter style is used for changing the base format message, but it has no impact on the replacement made by logger.warning and the likes. This does not solve OP's problem.

Comment: @JoachimJablon It is there in the link, you just need to scroll down a bit further - or ctrl+f for the codeblock containing `class StyleAdapter`.